# React-query not making the requests

Tags: reactjs, react-query

After doing some research on why I'm getting an `undefined` I noticed that no requests are being executed for some reason (chrome, "Network" tab shows no requests made to `/admin/cafes`).

At the moment, my code looks like this:

CafesTable.js

```
const fetchCafes = async () => {
  const res = await apiClient.get("/admin/cafes");
  return res;
};

function CafesTable() {
  const { data, status } = useQuery("cafes", fetchCafes);
  console.log(data);
```

the apiClient makes reference to:

```
const token = "Bearer " + Cookies.get("token");

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT}/api`,
  headers: {
    Authorization: token,
  },
});
```

which is inside `http-common.js`

Still, nothing is happening. Any idea why?

Comment: I think we need to see `apiClient`

Comment: apiClient comes from `import apiClient from "../../services/http-common";` which makes reference to `axios` @AdamThomas

Comment: Ah right I see, had misunderstood initially.

Comment: Are there no errors in console at all?

Comment: Nope, just returns "undefined," which is understandable since the request is not made, so `data` is empty.

Comment: Im wondering if its because your query key is not an array (which is the new way of doing it in react-query but dont know what version youre on). Try `useQuery(["cafes"], fetchCafes);`

Comment: I'm in the latest version. I'll try that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @AdamThomas suggested, the syntax changed for the newest version.

I refactored the code, and it now works. It looks like this:

```
const { data, status } = useQuery(["cafes"], () =>
    fetchCafes.then((res) => res.json())
  );
```

Comment: Wrong user btw  but good to hear! I had figured this out by making a codesandbox with your code. For me it did actually cause an error in console. You might want to look into why you werent seeing the errors (maybe accidental filter on dev tools or console.log overwritten?) as once I saw that the solution became clear.

Comment: Just edited the answer :) Not sure why I didn't get the error. It's weird

Comment: Might wanna check 100% youve not accidentally filtered logs by "info" or something on the dev tools. I do it all the time :D.